# Re-use schemas within BizTalk solution using XSD Import (Importing types from another schema/namespace)?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-schemas

I have crated schema project and use consume adapter service wizard to generate schema for SQL DB table to perform insert operation. (Filename Prefix : Batch_)

[image]

How to overcome with issue when I tried to reuse schemas and build new schemas (Common) out of existing types ?

[image]

So, when I  check Request schema node and try to find data structure type I got nothing ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, if this is still a problem: Could you please add more information about your problem? Maybe a step-by-step on what you did before hitting the problem?

Comment: Yes I’m having issue with making canonical (common) scheme and as you can see from attached screenshots there wasn’t any data structure type for “request” scheme node as I’m accepting to have ns0: and ns1 prefix scheme (screenshots 2)...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do.  But...it probably doesn't matter.

While technically possible, you really shouldn't be trying to craft your own schemas, just use what the Wizard emits directly.

With one exception, the common types, those you can consolidate because the xsd is the same for all generated Schemas.

More here: [BizTalk Server: Reducing and Consolidating WCF Serialization Schema Types](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24858.biztalk-server-reducing-and-consolidating-wcf-serialization-schema-types.aspx)